# How do I get wordpress to send user details through a rest API to Zendesk?

Tags: wordpress, rest, zendesk-api

I understand that this question might have been asked before, but looking at the answers is just making me more confused! I was wondering if someone could tell me the steps I should take to deliver this scenario?

1. A user is logged into my website
2. They open a live chat window (powered through Zendesk)

At this point, a live chat is opened in the zendesk support channel, but the name of the "user" is something generic like "Visitor 12345". I would like Wordpress to send the logged in users name and email address to Zendesk so the chat appears as "Member Name".

I think I need to use a Rest API for this. I have inputted the following code into my functions.php file. (which I found [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/widget/core#identify)).

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  zE('webWidget', 'identify', {
    name: 'Akira Kogane',
    email: 'akira@voltron.com',
    organization: 'Voltron, Inc.'
  });
</script>
```

But I am unsure of what to change "Akira Kogane" "akira@voltron.com" and "Voltron, Inc." to?

If anyone could point me to an idiots guide to setting WordPress up to be able to send this data I would really appreciate it. I would happily pay someone to do this work for me, but I would love to learn how to do it myself in the first place. I assume I have to set something up in wordpress, or set up a rest API somehow before it can send the data, but I'm not sure!

Thanks Again!

Comment: please change any potentially real info to fake info. eg "User Name, example@example.com"

Comment: Hi Joshua, Thanks for the reply. These already are fake info. There the standard email address used by Zendesk.